# What to do when a website says that my bc1... address is invalid?

Tags: wallet, bech32-address, address-format, localbitcoins

[image] I used local Bitcoins wallet to send bitcoin to my bitcoin wallet. But it said wrong address

Comment: What wallet software or app or device did you use to generate the bc1 address?  There may be a setting to have it generate a "legacy" address instead, starting with 1 or 3.

Answer (score 7):

The address that you are using starts with bc1 and is a bech32 address. Many online wallets still do not support this form of address, which is the reason you are getting the invalid Bitcoin address error. If you want to use segwit and still be compatible with these online wallets that do not support bech32, you can use a P2SH(P2WPKH) addresses that begin with 3.

Comment: Ugam Kamat ,Thanks but can you help me how to change the address?

Comment: @RehemaOlonya which wallet software are you using to generate the bc1 address?

Comment: @UgamKamat is right. You need to either pass a legacy address "1..." or a segwit compatible one "3...". If your wallet has the capability to generate native segwit address "bc1..." I'm sure you could get what you want!

Comment: @Ugamkamat I used my Android phone to download bitcoin wallet. When I downloaded the address came automatically

Comment: @RehemaOlonya ok, but which software did you use? Mycelium?

Comment: Bitcoin. Com is what I used

Comment: Ok, because it's important as your wallet should be segwit aware to spend bitcoins that are sent to P2SH(P2WPKH) addresses that begin with 3. You cannot generate one on the fly on anywebsite and import that address in any other wallet. You can do that only if you have the private key associated with the address.

Comment: @RehemaOlonya I'm still unsure how you got the bc1 address from bitcoin.com wallet. I have confirmed that they do not support native segwit addresses.